# Read list of files, and rewrite to master list

Tags: php, file-read, file-writing

I have a directory which has say 10 .txt files.  Open the directory using:

```
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
```

I need to be able to read the files names of the text files, and then write all those file names to a master list with a | after each file name.  I also do not want the masterlist.txt to be written inside itself lol.  So the masterlist.txt is what is being written to with the file names of the .txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the directory with `readdir()`, and verify that each entry isn't the master list or `.` or `..`. Write it to the file with `file_put_contents()`.

```
// If master.txt already exists, delete it.
if (file_exists('master.txt')) {
  unlink('master.txt');
}

$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 
while ($f = readdir($dir_handle)) {
  if ($f != '.' && $f != '..' && $f != 'master.txt') {
    file_put_contents('master.txt', $f . "|", FILE_APPEND);
  }
}
```

If you only want `.txt` files, use something like:

```
if (preg_match('/^(.+)\.txt$/', $f)) {
  // it's a .txt file.
}
```

Comment: Works awesome! How do I get it to override the master file instead of updating.  So each time it goes through the directory get's the file names, it will write to a clean/blank master file instead of just updated it.

Comment: See `file_exists()` addition above.  This will delete an existing master.txt before writing a new one.